# Concatenate row-wise across specific columns of dataframe

Tags: r, apply, paste, string-concatenation, sapply

I have a data frame with columns that, when concatenated (row-wise) as a string, would allow me to partition the data frame into a desired form.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   680420 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ A              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-26" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-09" ...
 $ B              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-27" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-10" ...
 $ C              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-26" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-09" ...
 $ D              : chr  "AAA" "AAA" "BCB" "CCC" ...
 $ E              : chr  "A00001" "A00002" "B00002" "B00001" ...
 $ F              : int  9 9 37 37 37 37 191 191 191 191 ...
 $ G              : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ H              : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

For each row, I would like to concatenate the data in columns F, E, D, and C into a string (with the underscore character as separator).  Below is my unsuccessful attempt at this:

```
data$id <- sapply(as.data.frame(cbind(data$F,data$E,data$D,data$C)), paste, sep="_")
```

And below is the undesired result:

```
  > str(data)
    'data.frame':   680420 obs. of  10 variables:
     $ A              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-26" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-09" ...
     $ B              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-27" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-10" ...
     $ C              : chr  "2011-01-26" "2011-01-26" "2011-02-09" "2011-02-09" ...
     $ D              : chr  "AAA" "AAA" "BCB" "CCC" ...
     $ E              : chr  "A00001" "A00002" "B00002" "B00001" ...
     $ F              : int  9 9 37 37 37 37 191 191 191 191 ...
     $ G              : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
     $ H              : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
     $ id             : chr [1:680420, 1:4] "9" "9" "37" "37" ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : NULL
      .. ..$ : chr  "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try

```
 data$id <- paste(data$F, data$E, data$D, data$C, sep="_")
```

instead.  The beauty of vectorized  code is that you do not need row-by-row loops, or loop-equivalent *apply functions.

*Edit*  Even better is

```
 data <- within(data,  id <- paste(F, E, D, C, sep=""))
```

Comment: Wow. That was quick and correct.  It looks like I was over-complicating the process.  I am really trying to wean myself off of complete 'loop dependency' and am still learning to appreciate vectorized code.

Comment: And try `with(data, paste(...))` for even more succinctness.

Comment: Correct. Or even `within()` as the less-loved cousin of `with()`. Amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: So that's how `within` differs!?! (Why the hell wasn't it named `with(..., modify=TRUE)` ?)

Comment: What if you use `data$id <- paste(data[, c(1)], data[,c(2)])`
oddly then the code doesn't do what expected. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: This answer looks awesome

Comment: If you want different separators between each column, you can use `paste0`: `paste0(df$col1,'-',df$col2,'.txt')`.  paste0 is a convenience function for specifying there is no separator.

Answer (score 13):

Use `unite` of `tidyr` package:

```
require(tidyr)
data <- data %>% unite(id, F, E, D, C, sep = '_')
```

First parameter is the desired name, all next up to `sep` - columns to concatenate.

Comment: When I needed to collapse dynamic vectors by groups, this method was the only one that consistently worked as such `mycols <- c("F","E","D","C")   data <- data %>% unite_("id", mycols, sep = "_")`

Answer (score 7):

Either `stringr::str_c()` or `paste()` will work.

```
require(stringr)
data <- within(data, str_c(F,E,D,C, sep="_")
```

or else

```
data <- within(data, paste(F,E,D,C, sep="_")
```

(`stringr` is better performance on large datasets)

Comment: @the serial downvoter: `stringr::str_c` can be used and noone said that. What's your problem?