# In R, concatenate numeric columns into a string while inserting some text elements

Tags: r, concatenation, string-concatenation

Here's a dataset - it's got an estimate of a quantity, along with two cells for the lower and upper bounds of a 95% confidence interval for that estimate:

```
d <- data.frame(estimate = c(380.3),
                low_95 = c(281.6),
                high_95 = c(405.7))
```

I'd like to concatenate each of these cells into one new string -- only I'd like to add some character elements so that the result is a single cell that looks like this:

`380.3 (281.6, 405.7)`

I've fiddled with `unite` in `dplyr` based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308933/concatenate-row-wise-across-specific-columns-of-dataframe), but I can't even get the numbers to stick together with an underscore, much less insert spaces, parentheses, and a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use the paste0 command that is part of the base R package, to concatenate strings in R. For example:

```
result <- paste0(d$estimate, " (", d$low_95, ", ", d$high_95, ")")
print(result)

[1] "380.3 (281.6, 405.7)"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sprintf` in `base R`

```
with(d, sprintf('%.1f (%.1f, %.1f)', estimate, low_95, high_95))
#[1] "380.3 (281.6, 405.7)"
```

Or without specifying the arguments one by one, use `do.call`

```
do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = '%.1f (%.1f, %.1f)', d))
#[1] "380.3 (281.6, 405.7)"
```

---

Or another option is `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
d %>% 
  glue_data("{estimate} ({low_95}, {high_95})")
#380.3 (281.6, 405.7)
```

Comment: @logjammin The example you showed is having only numeric columns.  If your original data is `character` class, then change it to `%s`.  Please check `str(d)` to check the class of each column